# Consultar Qual o Valor do Salário do Funcionário em uma Determinada Data

Tags: mysql, sql

Alguém sabe como seria uma query para consultar qual o valor do salário de um determinado funcionário em uma determinada data?

A tabela do histórico do reajuste do salário de cada funcionário possui os seguintes campos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> ```
> MATRICULA DATA    SALARIO_ANTERIOR    REAJUSTE    NOME    ADMISSAO_DATA   SALARIO_FIXO
> 000283  01.08.2009  4729.59 270.53  FULANO DA SILVA 13.07.2009  5982.48
> 000283  01.07.2010  5000.12 274.51  FULANO DA SILVA 13.07.2009  5982.48
> 000283  01.08.2011  5274.63 369.22  FULANO DA SILVA 13.07.2009  5982.48
> 000283  01.08.2012  5643.85 338.63  FULANO DA SILVA 13.07.2009  5982.48
> ```

Os campos ADMISSAO_DATA e SALARIO_FIXO são da tabela de Funcionários fiz um Join entre as tabelas de Historicos de Reajustes com Funcionarios onde gerou o resultado acima. O campo SALARIO_FIXO é da tabela de Funcionarios onde armazena sempre o salario atual após o último reajuste. No resultado acima está em 5982.48 após o reajuste feito em 01.08.2012 que anteriormente era de 5643.85.

Como eu faria para consultar, por exemplo qual era valor do salário desse funcionário de matricula 000283 em 01.05.2012? Não consegui desenvolver uma query para verificar e fazer a comparação para ver quanto era o salário nesta data desejada.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

---

Sorack, tudo bem?

Eu passei essa query para o Banco Mysql porém o último registro da consulta não consegue calcular o valor do salário atual após o último reajuste. Fica exatamente assim na imagem abaixo, seta o valor inicial antes do reajuste e a data ate fica setada a primeira data antes do reajuste, porém quando a query roda no SQL Fiddle roda corretamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado correto deveria sair assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A query feita por mim está assim:

`SELECT fr.matricula, fr.data, fr.salario_anterior, fr.reajuste, f.nome, f.admissao_data, f.salario_fixo
FROM funcionarios_reajustes fr
JOIN funcionarios AS f ON (f.matricula = fr.matricula)
WHERE tr.matricula = 00283
ORDER BY f.nome, fr.data ASC`

Comment: Você pode adicionar mais um filtro no WHERE filtrando apenas a data. `SELECT fr.matricula, 
fr.data, 
fr.salario_anterior, 
fr.reajuste, 
f.nome, 
f.admissao_data, 
f.salario_fixo 
FROM funcionarios_reajustes fr 
JOIN funcionarios AS f 
 ON (f.matricula = fr.matricula) 
 WHERE tr.matricula = 00283 
 AND fr.data BETWEEN '20120501 00:00:00' and '20120501 23:59:59'
 ORDER BY f.nome, fr.data ASC`

Comment: O outro select para selecionar em determinada data está assim:

`SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN '01.08.2009' < data THEN salario_anterior
        WHEN '01.07.2010' < data THEN salario_anterior
        WHEN '01.08.2011' < data THEN salario_anterior
        WHEN '01.08.2012' < data THEN salario_anterior
    END AS salario
FROM (SELECT fr.matricula, fr.data, fr.salario_anterior, fr.reajuste, f.nome, f.admissao_data, f.salario_fixo
FROM funcionarios_reajustes fr
JOIN funcionarios AS t ON (f.matricula = fr.matricula))
WHERE matricula = 00283 AND data = '01.05.2012'`

Comment: @JorgitodaSilvaPaiva fiz uma edição na minha resposta para corrigir os problemas com relação a múltiplas matrículas. Verifique por favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu problema todo ocorre porque as tabelas parecem estar modeladas de maneira complicada demais para o problema que deve ser resolvido. Eu sugiro que, se possível, seja criada uma tabela `salario` que tenha o valor, início da vigência e valor do salário, assim o problema será facilmente resolvido. Caso não possa alterar a estrutura, utilize a seguinte `query` para extrair os valores esperados:

```
SELECT x.matricula,
       x.tipo,
       x.salario,
       x.de,
       x.ate,
       x.reajuste
  FROM (-- Pega apenas os primeiros salários
        SELECT y1.*
          FROM (SELECT 'Contratação' AS tipo,
                       -- Caso ainda não possua reajuste utiliza a data atual como referência de final
                       COALESCE(DATE_SUB(fr.data, INTERVAL 1 DAY), CURDATE()) AS ate,
                       f.admissao_data AS de,
                       -- Caso não possua registro de reajuste utiliza o salario_fixo
                       COALESCE(fr.salario_anterior, f.salario_fixo) AS salario,
                       NULL AS salario_anterior,
                       NULL AS reajuste,
                       f.matricula
                  FROM funcionarios f
                       -- LEFT para caso seja o primeiro salário do funcionário
                       LEFT JOIN funcionarios_reajustes fr ON fr.matricula = f.matricula
                 -- Pega apenas os registros que não possuam anterior (primeiros)
                 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                                    FROM funcionarios_reajustes fr2
                                   WHERE fr2.matricula = f.matricula
                                     AND fr2.data < fr.data)
                 ORDER BY fr.data) y1
         UNION
        -- Demais salários
        SELECT y2.*
          FROM (SELECT 'Reajuste' AS tipo,
                       CASE @matricula
                         -- Se não for o último utiliza a data do próximo reajuste menos 1 dia
                         WHEN fr.matricula THEN DATE_SUB(@data_proximo, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                         -- Se for o último utiliza a data atual para referência de valor final
                         ELSE CURDATE()
                       END AS ate,
                       @data_proximo := fr.data AS de,
                       CASE @matricula
                         -- Se não for o último utiliza o valor do próximo reajuste
                         WHEN fr.matricula THEN @salario_anterior
                         -- Se for o último faz o cálculo
                         ELSE fr.salario_anterior + fr.reajuste
                       END AS salario,
                       @salario_anterior := fr.salario_anterior AS salario_anterior,
                       fr.reajuste,
                       @matricula := fr.matricula AS matricula
                  FROM funcionarios_reajustes fr
                 ORDER BY fr.matricula, fr.data DESC) y2
         ) x
 WHERE x.matricula = '000283'
   AND STR_TO_DATE('15/07/2011', '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN x.de AND x.ate
 ORDER BY x.matricula,
          x.de
```

A query anterior:

- Pega o valor do registro mais antigo para saber qual o primeiro salário do funcionário;
- Realiza junção do registro com os calculados;
- Reune os dados ordenados pelas datas mais novas primeiro;
- Utiliza variáveis de controle que são preenchidas no registro anterior (ou seja, mais novo). Assim o salário atual é preenchido e a data de vigência;
- Na conjunto de resultados é realizado o filtro pela data desejada.

**Observação:** Sugiro que você crie uma `VIEW` com a `query` acima para facilitar a legibilidade e reutilização.

---

Veja funcionando no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72925e/5).

---

Caso queira seguir a orientação de criar outra tabela, a sugestão seria a seguinte:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS salario(
  codigo    INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  matricula VARCHAR(6),
  salario   DECIMAL(15, 2),
  inicio    DATE,
  CONSTRAINT pk_salario PRIMARY KEY(codigo),
  CONSTRAINT fk_salario_funcionarios FOREIGN KEY(matricula) REFERENCES funcionarios(matricula)
);
```

E para popular:

```
INSERT INTO salario(matricula,
                    salario,
                    inicio)
SELECT x.matricula,
       x.salario,
       x.de
  FROM (-- Pega apenas os primeiros salários
        SELECT y1.*
          FROM (SELECT 'Contratação' AS tipo,
                       -- Caso ainda não possua reajuste utiliza a data atual como referência de final
                       COALESCE(DATE_SUB(fr.data, INTERVAL 1 DAY), CURDATE()) AS ate,
                       f.admissao_data AS de,
                       -- Caso não possua registro de reajuste utiliza o salario_fixo
                       COALESCE(fr.salario_anterior, f.salario_fixo) AS salario,
                       NULL AS salario_anterior,
                       NULL AS reajuste,
                       f.matricula
                  FROM funcionarios f
                       -- LEFT para caso seja o primeiro salário do funcionário
                       LEFT JOIN funcionarios_reajustes fr ON fr.matricula = f.matricula
                 -- Pega apenas os registros que não possuam anterior (primeiros)
                 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                                    FROM funcionarios_reajustes fr2
                                   WHERE fr2.matricula = f.matricula
                                     AND fr2.data < fr.data)
                 ORDER BY fr.data) y1
         UNION
        -- Demais salários
        SELECT y2.*
          FROM (SELECT 'Reajuste' AS tipo,
                       CASE @matricula
                         -- Se não for o último utiliza a data do próximo reajuste menos 1 dia
                         WHEN fr.matricula THEN DATE_SUB(@data_proximo, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                         -- Se for o último utiliza a data atual para referência de valor final
                         ELSE CURDATE()
                       END AS ate,
                       @data_proximo := fr.data AS de,
                       CASE @matricula
                         -- Se não for o último utiliza o valor do próximo reajuste
                         WHEN fr.matricula THEN @salario_anterior
                         -- Se for o último faz o cálculo
                         ELSE fr.salario_anterior + fr.reajuste
                       END AS salario,
                       @salario_anterior := fr.salario_anterior AS salario_anterior,
                       fr.reajuste,
                       @matricula := fr.matricula AS matricula
                  FROM funcionarios_reajustes fr
                 ORDER BY fr.matricula, fr.data DESC) y2
         ) x
 WHERE x.matricula = '000283'
   AND STR_TO_DATE('15/07/2011', '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN x.de AND x.ate
 ORDER BY x.matricula,
          x.de
```

Comment: Sorack, mas o resultado não foi o esperado, pois veja bem a consulta foi qual o valor do salário em 15/07/2011, certo? Então o valor deveria ser de 5274.63 pois esse era o valor antes do reajuste feito em 01/08/2011. O resultado esta apresentando o valor do salário após o reajuste, no caso o valor de 5643.85.

Comment: Perfeito Sorack, mas caso desejasse saber o valor antes do primeiro reajuste no caso antes de 01/08/2009, por exemplo coloque a data de 13/09/2009 quando o funcionário foi contratado e o salário inicial de 4729.59

Comment: Ok @Sorack aguardo então, desde já agradeço a sua ajuda.

Comment: agradeço muito a sua ajuda, muito obrigado mesmo pela disposição, vou estudar bem esse sql para compreender direito, não lembrava dessa função COALESCE. Valeu mesmo!!!!!!

Comment: Sorack devo inserir um comentário aceitando a resposta como correta?

Comment: Sorack, tudo bem?
Eu passei essa query para o Banco Mysql porém o último registro da consulta não consegue calcular o valor do salário atual após o último reajuste. Fica exatamente assim:

4729.59 2009-07-13 2009-07-31 
5000.12 2009-08-01 2010-06-30 270.53
5274.63 2010-07-01 2011-07-31 274.51
5643.85 2011-08-01 2012-07-31 369.22
4729.59 2012-08-01 2009-07-31 338.63

Não consegui entender pq não consegue calcular. Teria como você ver se consegue ver pq não calcula???